# Cannot open files with Emacs after mounting Google Drive on Ubuntu using ocamlfuse

Tags: mount, emacs, google-drive, fuse

I have installed a [FUSE filesystem for Google Drive](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse) so that I can mount my Drive on Ubuntu. It's something I have done before on other machines with no problem.

Everything is installed and mounted okay. I can navigate to my newly mounted files:

```
/home/my-account/googledrive/myfiles
```

The weird thing is that I can open and edit my files using the text editor `vi` for example, but when I try to open the files with `emacs` I get the error:

```
cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be the version of my Emacs. I updated that and everything seems fine now!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1345860)